# How do I set action properties?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-opengraph

Maybe I missed it, but in all the Open Graph documentation I didn't see how to specify action properties when publishing an action.

The POST example given was:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/YOUR_NAMESPACE:cook
?recipe=OBJECT_URL&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

If I define a custom property (like "amount"), how do I assign that?  I took a stab in the dark and tried the following, but it doesn't appear to have worked:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/YOUR_NAMESPACE:cook
?recipe=OBJECT_URL&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&amount=5
```

Answer (score 1):

Click "Get Code" on the index page of you ActionType. It should be the name of your property as you guessed.

Let me know what was wrong.

Comment: I click "Get Code", but the property that I added is not mentioned anywhere.